# Retrieve unexpected exception type and message

Tags: c++, linux

I have a project using extensively exception specification and I often have exception being thrown violating the exception list.

Those result in a call to `unexpected()` and `__cxa_call_unexpected ()`. As per the specification I can call [set_unexpected](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/set_unexpected/) to override the default behaviour of calling `terminate`.

This allows me to have the exception rethrown as a `std::bad_exception` but then I've lost the original exception information message.

Is there anything I can do to intercept the actual unexpected exception message?

Code to reproduce:

```
void myunexpected () 
{
    throw 0;     // throws int (in exception-specification)
}

void test() throws(std::bad_exception)
{
     throw new std::invalid_argument("I i'de like to print this");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::set_unexpected (myunexpected);

    try {
        test();
    } catch(std::bad_exception& e) {
        qDebug() << e.what();
    }

}
```

This gives as output: `std::bad_exception`

Comment: See if [`std::current_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) helps. Not sure if it's available in `unexpected` handler.

Comment: Dynamic exception specifications are deprecated as of C++11, because they're useless. [Here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm) is Herb Sutter's take from 2002 (approximately when most people stopped using them).